# three.js progressive rendering of large mesh

Tags: javascript, performance, graphics, three.js, webgl

I would like to render a static mesh that is arbitrarily large using three.js. The mesh could be 2 GB with tens of millions of polygons.

I want to stream the mesh geometry buffers into indexedDB and progressively read them out and render them to the screen, while maintaining an interactive frame rate. I will create a MemoryManager class that makes sure we do not crash the browser by loading the data into a fixed-size buffer from indexedDB. In my animation loop I will render as many geometries as I can within 16ms, until the user stops interacting, then continuously render meshes until there are no more.

That is the high-level approach I want to take, of course there are many optimizations that will need to be done. ( object pools, octree, occlusion queries, etc)

My question is this: ***is there a better way to do this, and has it been done before?*** ( with WebGL1, I know WebGL2 occlusion queries would make this much simpler)

Also, what is the best way to customize the Three.js WebGLRenderer class? There are private closure vars ( like WebGLState ) that I will need access to tweak the performance for my use case.

Comment: Re: WebGLRenderer short of forking there isn’t really a good way. A few versions ago, a lot of the internals were exposed so you could monkey patch it to an extent. There’s a lot more encapsulation going on now, but the good news is it’s “fairly” modular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe WebGL2 occlusion queries will help you a whole lot here. It might be possible to use them, but doing culling on the cpu is probably a better option, especially if your scene is largely static.

If you want to progressively render in geometry while the user has stopped interacting, then you can just stop clearing the render buffer. With THREE.js you can do this by enabling `preserveDrawingBuffer` on the renderer and setting `autoClear` to `false`.

If the camera moves or the scene otherwise changes and you need to start over, you can clear the view again by calling `renderer.clear()`.

Regarding streaming data in, I would use [BufferGeometry](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/BufferGeometry) and modify the necessary [BufferAttributes](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/BufferAttribute) every frame. And it sounds like you have already have some ideas around optimizing and deciding which geometry needs to be rendered.

#### Example

Scene redraws on the same frame over and over. Click the scene to clear it and start drawing again. The important js lines are `NOTE`'d

```js
// NOT: enabling preserveDrawingBuffer
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, preserveDrawingBuffer: true });
renderer.setClearColor(0x263238);
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
renderer.clear();
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

// NOTE: disabling autoclear
renderer.autoClear = false;

// Scene setup
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const dirLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
dirLight.position.set(.4, 1, .1);
scene.add(dirLight);

// Camera setup
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 2000)
camera.position.z = 10;

const geom = new THREE.TorusKnotGeometry(.5, .2, 200, 100);
const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geom, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xE91E63 }));
scene.add(mesh);


// NOTE: Clearing on user interaction
renderer.domElement.addEventListener('click', () => renderer.clear());

(function renderLoop() {
    mesh.position.y = Math.sin(performance.now() * 0.001);
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
    requestAnimationFrame( renderLoop );
})();
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/r92/build/three.js"></script>

<style>
  canvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
  }

  div {
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
  }
</style>

<div>Click to clear</div>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks that is a great answer. I agree with the BufferGeometry approach I'll give that a try.